# App store rejected app due to firebase test phone number not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, testflight

Our app was rejected over 5 times now, with the apple review tester claiming that they could not login with the test creds provided that has been added to our firebase test phone number authentication pool. However, when we test it with the build grabbing it from test flight we are able to login. Anyone have any ideas? I have exhausted most of mine.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asked via comment, I will post my answer here.

The problem was that I had to use a phone number that is not considered real in the US, so I used 555-555-5555 instead of the phone number that I claimed as a test.